# Two instances of user control one instance react on event other don't

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have one user control. Two instances of user control one instance react on event other don't.

Some advice?

Comment: impossible to comment without code indicating where you subscribe to the event, and what the event-handler does.

Comment: Code is to big. I am asking in general. I guess that one instance of user control have all data, other don't.

Comment: @Ivan - you aren't expected to post the entire thing; just something that gives us some broad context, and illustrates that you are actually subscribing. In fact, the more you can reduce it to a simple, reproducible example -  the better.

Comment: Instead of requesting code, have you noticed we don't know if it's ASP.NET, WPF or SL?

Comment: @Matías that too ;p (or, of course, winforms, CF, XNA, ...)

Comment: Then, it comes to my mind that no one will help you if you don't explain code context, code itself and you provide some code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the user control,

First Name:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RQV1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxFirstName" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Last Name:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RQV2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxLastName" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here is the Code-behind for the page exposing public properties,

```
public string GetFirstName
{
    get { return TextBoxFirstName.Text; }
    set { TextBoxFirstName.Text = value; }
}

public string GetLastName
{
    get { return TextBoxLastName.Text; }
    set { TextBoxLastName.Text = value; }
}
```

In the code-behind, I am creating two public string variables setting the value to the TextBox control's Text property and returning the Text property of the TextBox controls.

Then, in the main page,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>This is page to add multiple user controls.</div>
<p>
    Customer1 Details:<br />
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
</p>

<p>
    Customer2 Details:<br />
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl12" runat="server" />           
</p>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Continue" OnClick="GetCustDetails"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Clear" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="ClearFields" /><br />

Customer1 FirstName: <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:label><br />
Customer1 LastName: <asp:label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:label><br />
Customer2 FirstName: <asp:label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:label><br />
Customer2 LastName: <asp:label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:label><br />
</form>
```

I am adding two instances of the user control to the page. Then there are four Label controls that will display the user control's properties on Button1 click. There is another Button2 that clears all the user control's TextBox controls.

```
protected void GetCustDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = WebUserControl11.GetFirstName;
    Label2.Text = WebUserControl11.GetLastName;
    Label3.Text = WebUserControl12.GetFirstName;
    Label4.Text = WebUserControl12.GetLastName;
}

protected void ClearFields(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl11.GetFirstName = string.Empty;
    WebUserControl11.GetLastName = string.Empty;
    WebUserControl12.GetFirstName = string.Empty;
    WebUserControl12.GetLastName = string.Empty;
}
```